# Sprites for server performance

Tags: performance, css-sprites

Does using sprites improve server side performance from the decrease in requests processed? How much is the overhead of opening a connection for a file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683221/how-do-css-sprites-speed-up-a-web-site

Comment: The answers do not discuss the effect on server load, just page load speeds

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for bandwidth and i/o, a spritesheet will win hands down every time over 10 different images. I'm slightly unsure about what you're specifically asking though!